# Email Deliverbility

Tags: email, deliverability

How can I enable permissions to edit Email Deliverability access level? Currently it is not editable and in system mode. I need to edit it and set it to "**All Email** so I can test Approval and workflow functionality.

[image: Non Editable View of Access level]

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

> New and refreshed sandboxes have the default email deliverability
>   setting System email only. To configure email deliverability settings,
>   in the sandbox org, from Setup, enter Deliverability in the Quick Find
>   box, then select Deliverability. If editable, set the Access level in
>   the Access to Send Email section. You can’t edit the Access level if
>   Salesforce has restricted your organization’s ability to change this
>   setting.

to change it to any another desired value, you need to create a salesforce support case